# JavaScript working fine In IE, Firefox and Opera but not in Safari or Chrome (Textbox.value)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

The JavaScript code below is executed every time the user selects the login button on my webpage, the function basically ensures that the `username` and `password` fields have received text (and then strips away any leading or trailing white space) and then redirects the browser to the php login script. The code works perfectly in IE, Firefox and Opera yet it doesn't in Safari and Chrome.

In Safari and Chrome, the textbox values are `undefined`. Other browsers return the values typed perfectly.

```
var button;
var name;
var pass;

function logIn()
{

    name.value = name.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    pass.value = pass.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

    if(name.value == "")
    {

        alert("Please Enter A Username");

    }

    else if(pass.value == "")
    {

        alert("Please Enter A Password");

    }

    else
    {

        window.location.href = "loginScript.php?username=" + name.value + "&password=" + pass.value;

    }

}

function onLoad()
{

    button = document.getElementById('button');
    name = document.getElementById('username');
    pass = document.getElementById('password');

    button.onclick = logIn;

}

window.onload = onLoad;
```

Comment: I would suggest not putting the password in the URL.

Comment: Where is name and pass assigned?

Comment: what happens in Safari or Chrome if you don't strip the whitespace off?

Comment: at least hash the password before putting it in the URL.

Comment: @11684 Haha...dont worry about passing passwords in the URL or hashing them...this is performed on the PHP page when the browser get re-directed to it (it doesnt produce anyput, it checks the database so that the username and passwords are correct and then re-directs the user accordingly)! I think you could be onto something with removing the replace() lines tho...the function actually executes now but it wont log the user in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the variable you're using, name, is a reserved keyword in Chrome.

Try changing the name variable to something like username.

```
var button;
var username;
var password;

function logIn()
{

    username.value = username.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    pass.value = pass.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

    if(username.value == "")
    {

        alert("Please Enter A Username");

    }

    else if(password.value == "")
    {

        alert("Please Enter A Password");

    }

    else
    {

        window.location.href = "loginScript.php?username=" + username.value + "&password=" + password.value;

    }

}

function onLoad()
{

    button = document.getElementById('button');
    username = document.getElementById('username');
    password= document.getElementById('password');

    button.onclick = logIn;

}

window.onload = onLoad;
```

EDIT: Changed pass to password as well

Comment: If you had printed your name and pass variables to the Chrome console you'd see that they print out differently. It's because the pass variable contains a valid DOM element and name had.. something else. console.log(name,pass);

Comment: Thanks again....I'm a bit old fashioned when it comes to testing javascript just...I usually just make do with alert(variableName)!

Comment: Haha, I used to until I discovered just how powerful the dev console is! You can expand objects, arrays, and DOM elements to see their properties and attributes. Very, VERY useful ;)

Comment: This solution works perfectly in Chrome however not in Safari...i'm assumming pass is also a reserved keyword in the webkit used by Safari (based on the fact it is highlighted in the above codeblock)...by changing pass to another variable name such as pw resolves this problem (in the same manner as suggested by @TheZ)!

Comment: Updated then! Keywords can sometimes crop up out of nowhere! xD